# Using Fastmember to bulk insert only selected columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, fastmember

I have an application that is being used to insert large amounts of data (up to about 250,000 records per file) from a file to a table that has several computed columns. Is there any way to select which columns fastmember inserts the data so I don't try writing into the computed columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(YourConnectionString))
            {
                // +1 to Marc Gravell for this neat little library to do the mapping for us
                // because DataTable isn't available until .NET Standard Library 2.0
                using (var dataReader = ObjectReader.Create(yourListOfObjects,
                    nameof(YourClass.Property1),
                    nameof(YourClass.Property2)))
                {
                    bcp.DestinationTableName = "YourTableNameInSQL";
                    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Property1", "MyCorrespondingTableColumn"));
                    bcp.ColumnMappings.Add(new SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping("Property2", "TableProperty2"));


                    await bcp.WriteToServerAsync(dataReader).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Model class:

```
class ExampleModel
{
    public int property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
    public string property3 { get; set; }       
}
```

List Of Model:

```
private List<ExampleModel> listOfObject = new List<ExampleModel>()
{
    new ExampleModel { property1 = 1, property2 = 'Rudra',  property3 = 'M'},
    new ExampleModel { property1 = 2, property2 = 'Shivam', property3 = 'M'}
};
```

Bulk insert using [Fastmember](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/) with column mapping:

```
  using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLConnectionString))
  using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(listOfObject))
  {
      bcp.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[tablename]";
      bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("property1", "tableCol1");
      bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("property2", "tableCol2");
      bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("property3", "tableCol3");
      bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
  }
```

Remember:

Insert data with identity field do not forget to use KeepIdentity.

```
using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
```

Insert data with auto increment identity field, remove auto increment column mapping field. like property1 is auto increment column in database so skip this column while insert data.

```
      using (var bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLConnectionString))
      using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(listOfObject))
      {
          bcp.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[tablename]";
          bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("property2", "tableCol2");
          bcp.ColumnMappings.Add("property3", "tableCol3");
          bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
      }
```